# Why isn't the Gemara Megillah 16b more direct with its sources?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tefilin, purim, megillat-esther

The [Gemara Megillah 16b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.16b.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi#:%7E:text=%D7%B4%D7%9C%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%94%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%93%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%94,%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%A0%D6%B9%D7%9B%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%AA%D6%B6%D7%9A%D6%B8%D7%B4) selection of the pasuk from Devarim ([28:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.28?lang=bi&aliyot=0#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%90%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%9B%D6%BC%D7%87%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%99%20%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B6%D7%A5%20%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B5%D7%9D%20%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B9%D7%95%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%A7%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%90%20%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%9C%D6%B6%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%90%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9A%D6%BC%D6%B8)) to explain the term וִיקָר is quite puzzling.
It appears that it would have been more fitting and straightforward for the gemara to choose a less intricate pasuk, especially one of the four primary pesukim directly associated with the mitzvah of tefillin ([Shemos 13:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.13.9?lang=bi&aliyot=0#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%93%D6%B0%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%96%D6%B4%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%A8%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D6%B6%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9F%20%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%94%D6%B0%D7%99%D6%B6%D7%94%20%D7%AA%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B9%D7%95%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%A4%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%93%20%D7%97%D6%B2%D7%96%D6%B8%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A6%D6%B4%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B9%D7%95%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%A6%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%9D), [Shemos 13:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.13.16?lang=bi&aliyot=0#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%93%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%98%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%98%D6%B8%D7%A4%D6%B9%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D6%B6%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%97%D6%B9%D7%96%D6%B6%D7%A7%20%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%93%20%D7%94%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A6%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%A0%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B9%D7%95%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%A6%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%9D), [Devarim 6:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A7%D6%B0%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%93%D6%B6%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%99%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%98%D6%B9%D7%98%D6%B8%D7%A4%D6%B9%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D6%B6%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8), [Devarim 11:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.18?lang=bi&aliyot=0#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%D6%BE%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%99%20%D7%90%D6%B5%D7%9C%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%91%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%B6%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%A0%D6%B7%D7%A4%D6%B0%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%B6%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A7%D6%B0%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D6%B9%D7%AA%D6%B8%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%99%D6%B6%D7%93%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%B6%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%99%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%98%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%98%D6%B8%D7%A4%D6%B9%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%9B%D6%B6%D7%9D)), which are actually contained inside the tefillin.

Is this question asked by any of the mefarshim?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the gemara can't use any of the four main tefillin Pessukim is because they are trying to *darshen* the meaning behind "ויקר". Seeing as none of those Pessukim that word or a similar one, it would be impossible to understand that ויקר refers to tefillin from any of them.

The passuk used, however, does include a similar word "נקרא". Therefore, the gemara *darshens* that ויקר has the same meaning as נקרא, and then says that the passuk of נקרא refers to tefillin, which in turn means that ויקר does as well.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is this your own explanation, i don't see that from the pshat of the gemara.

Comment: @TheTargum this is my own understanding of the gemara. Many times the gemara learns things in this way. In fact, in this gemara itself learns שש to mean bris milah from a similarly "random" passuk

Comment: I'd actually make the argument that what stands out from the gemaras use of the pasuk for tefillin is that it does NOT have the root word in the pasuk. But,  appreciate and like your chdush.